# Jenkins environment variables using the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github, environment-variables

Is it possible to set git repo as an environment variable?

Ex. I am trying to create a drop down that will let the user choose which project to build including which branch to use. I was able to view the branch as a drop but id like to create a choice parameter that allows the user to choose which repo they'd like to build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin).

This plugin adds "Extensible Choice" as a build parameter.You can select how to retrieve choices, including the way to share choices among all jobs.